# Highcharts problem - showing labels in zoomable chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, label

I have a zoom column chart with more then 200 categories in xAxis. Consequently, when it is in the initial state (scale 1:1), all these guys are shown under the X axis, and it's impossible to read anything even if I place them vertically. I need to zoom the chart to make the labels visible.

Here's screenshot of the problem: 
[image]

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/sherlock85/hJcQm/

Is it possible to adjust the concentration of the labels (perhaps change the step automatically) depending on a zoom level?

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Andrzej

Answer (score 3):

In order from easiest to most difficult...

Since your categories are mostly numeric (e.g. 'mir001'), you could omit the categories, which would prevent them from all being displayed. They would then show 1, 2, 3, and so on.

Alternatively, you could remove the categories and use a [label formatter](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--formatter). In this case, you could do something like this, again taking advantage of the fact that the labels appear to be numeric and increasing:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    xaxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return "mir" + this.value;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Both of the above would reduce the number of labels (the labels would follow some pattern such as 1, 50, 100, until zoomed).

If you wanted to be very particular about the labels, you would have to use the label formatter and do some math to find the scale of the graph to determine how the labels should be displayed. You could, for example, do something like this, though it is quite convoluted:

```
var categories = [] //have your categories as a separate list
var buckets = 4; 
var labelFormatter = function(frequency) {
    var count = 0;
    frequency = frequency || 0;
    return function () {
        count++;
        if ((count > frequency) || (frequency < 1)) {
                return this.value
        }
    }
};

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    zoomtype: 'x',
    events: {
        selection: function(event) {
            if (event.xAxis) {
                var scale = event.xAxis[0];
                var frequency = Math.floor((scale.max - scale.min) / buckets)
                this.xaxis[0].labels.formatter = labelFormatter(frequency);
            }
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: labelFormatter(Math.floor(categories.length/buckets))
        }
    }
});
```

I should point out that the last solution doesn't exactly work, further illustrating how difficult it is.

Comment: Thank you very much NT3RP for such a rapid reply. Ideally, I dream of the following chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail I figured out how to display bars, but I absolutely don't know how can I put my categories, instead of the datatype from this example. I spent hours trying to modify this example, but still nothing. If you could look at it I would be really grateful.

Comment: The reason the example works is because it uses a datetime for the x-axis, which has special support built into highcharts. What exactly is your x-axis supposed to represent?

Comment: My xaxis represents names of RNA molecules (e.g. mir989, mir234a, mir547b) and these are just strings. Each molecule has its own expression level in cell and this is pointed by yaxis. The problem is the increasing number of these RNAs so I need to have a column chart with sliding window. I'm helpless at this point. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, what would it look like when zoomed out all the way. Would it just show a few of the labels until you get close?

Comment: NT3RP, thank you very much for your concern. In my matter there are two possibilities I can think of. First is your idea (the best for me) where all the labels are visible until I get close enough, but in scale 1:1 there are just a few. In other solution, the chart might be in fixed scale (for example: only 50 bars with labels) so I can slide along the xaxis with window of the fixed size. But your idea is exactly what I need. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I'll see if I can some up with something for tomorrow. On the face of it though, probably not, because there isn't an easy way to tell the zoom level.

Comment: Thank you, NT3RP. I would be really grateful.

Comment: NT3RP, sorry for late reply. It turned out, that the issue of crowded labels was discussed on highcharts forum earlier. In this case, highcharts supporters recommend to use 'fake' categories. You can achieve that in 3 steps:
1. Define categories as global variable.
2. Set allowDecimals to false in xAxis options
3. Use axis label formatter which return something like: categories[this.value] See: http://jsfiddle.net/hJcQm/18/

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
xAxis:
{
    categories: [ <!-- your categories -->],
    tickInterval: 5,        // Cada 5 valores muestra valor (five jump interval)
    labels:
    {
        rotation: -35,
        style:
        {
            font: 'normal 12px Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit too late for the original question, but I'm developing something with Highcharts and I was looking for exactly for this.

Here's how I did it, for future reference:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        step: 5
    },
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(event) {
            if (event.max) {
                var frequency = Math.floor((event.max - event.min) / 17);
                this.options.labels.step = frequency;
            } else {
                this.options.labels.step = 5;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It basically checks if we're zooming - `if (event.max)` - or resetting. 17 is the number of labels I get when zoomed out, with labels step set to 5 and with this particular data set (I'm pretty sure this could all be more polished - but it works).

Answer (score 0):

This is I how solved this problem:

```
xAxis: {
   tickPositioner: function () {
      var positions = [],
          min = Math.floor(this.min),
          max = Math.ceil(this.max),
          tick = min,
          increment = Math.ceil((max - min) / 30);

      for (; tick < max; tick += increment) {
         positions.push(tick);
      }
      positions.push(max);
      return positions;
   }
}
```

The tickPositioner get called on a redraw. The min and max contain the left and right most (x-axis) inclusive values.