# Dual axes line vs column and zoom tooltip broke

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem when I try to make a dual axes chart and I use Chart 1 = column and Chart 2 = line. 
The Chart 1 (column) has many nulls, and, over 00:00 each day, one value no zero. The problem cause that, when I make zoom over the chart, and I put the onmouseover to the Chart 1, the tooltip broke it and the chart it's freezed until you make another zoom over other zone.
My fiddle:

```
[code]
http://jsfiddle.net/revor44/9vbX7/
[/code]
```

It's a quick example.

Make zoom, and see the tooltip over column chart.

What's is my problem? It could be possible fix it?

Comment: Check Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831428/highcharts-problem-showing-labels-in-zoomable-chart

Comment: I have tried do the first "solution" and it doens't works. The problem appear when I do zoom... it's how the zoom can't "look for" the column position date. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/revor44/4BXuJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution is to remove all nulls (are they necessary?) and just use `[x,y]` format for columns, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4BXuJ/2/