# Column interval and tooltip mistake

Tags: highcharts

A few days ago I posted a question with problem in column chart:
[Dual axes line vs column and zoom tooltip broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849445/dual-axes-line-vs-column-and-zoom-tooltip-broke)

I don't want to refloat this thread. Sorry for that.

I thought that the problem was a series with many "nulls" and Fusher answered me with one "solution". Well, I think that this mistake I doesn't happens only with many "nulls". Some of my charts, at present, are failing even with no "nulls" values. This jdfiffle it's an quick example with official jdfiffle code:

```
[code]
http://jsfiddle.net/revor44/D2vLX/
[/code]
```

If you do zoom over the final serie and you try to see the tooltip, you will see how the tooltip it's fixed to the left zone inside the chart. Even, when you have a "complex" tooltip (with large series name and html) the tooltip it's displaced. I have taken a screenshot.

This happen when the series have many daily values. If I use date column interval with... 30 days, it doesn't happen. In return, when I have 90 values, for example, appears the problem.

Is there no solution using many values with date interval column? By the architecture of my program I need to use this configuration. In fact, in past version of highcharts it doesn't happens (or 2 earlier). Problem? I can't come back because this version fixes other mistakes.

Sorry for my insistence but it's important to me and the corporative development.

Thank you so much and best regards.

The screeshot I can't post it. if someone could tell me how to do it, I would appreciate.

---

I have seen few hours ago that the bug has fixed and closed... here:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1526

I have been testing the new version, and It doesn`t fix the error, at least, in Highcharts. I downloaded the master files from here:
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com

With these files I tried make zoom in the same chart from the jsdfiddle what it's up. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks for your time!!.

Comment: Yeah, I reported that bug a few days ago: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1526

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus, thanks for report the bug. I saw the thread about this bug, but It doesn't only occurs  in HighSctock, in fact, my problem is in Highcharts. I only want notice you this comment.